Wifi connectivity issue
Hello I hope I can get help we are living in an apartment type of building wherein lot is connected when I came from work I connected to it then after I accidentally tap another connection I lost it and I never returned to that same thing with turning off my wifi signal on phone it will happen everytime only 1 time then another day again I can try connecting midnight
[enter code here][1]


Please add some detail and clarity to your question; currently, it is quite hard to determine what you are actually asking.

Wifi connection 2.4Hz/5Ghz the one that can work inside the room is giving me trouble connecting to it it only gave me 1 chance to connect when I was from work then after I switch to another network I can't connect to it anymore even multiple times I tried

Have you reset your router? What have you already tried?
